# multilingual site: how create clean relationship between "static" texts (coded into templates) and database?

Tags: django, multilingual

On a multilingual (manually translated) website appropriate translations of products or newspaper-articles are pulled out according to user (or user-selected) language. But what about all those annoying "static" texts that ordinarily get coded directly into a template? Perhaps "opening hours" or "contact us"? Obviously these need to exist in various translations (and therefore in the database), my question is how to develop clearly the relationship between database entry and code?

So far was thinking of the following:

```py
MODELS
Language
name

Article
article_title
article_slug

Translation
article =models.ForeignKey(Article)
language =models.ForeignKey(Language)
title_text
article_text


VIEWS
def page12view(request)
   article = article.objects.get(slug='friendly-name-of-article')
   query = Translation.objects.filter(article=article).filter(language=request.user.language)
   if not query.first(): #if translation not available in user’s language default to ENGLISH (pk=1)
       query = Translation.objects.filter(article=article).filter(language=1)
   context = { ‘friendly-name-of-article’: query.first()}
   return render (request,’page12.html', context)

TEMPLATE

{{friendly-name-of-article.title_text}}
{{friendly-name-of-article.article_text}}
```

The idea revolves around giving each article a slug (referred to in above example as "friendly-name-of-article"). Thus "about-us", "opening-hours"etc.. That string would be copy-pasted in the view and template as suggested in the code. The idea is that it would at least bring some clarity as to what is going on. But is it a good idea? Have my doubts... Any good practices to share?

Comment: So do you want to translate variable name?

Comment: Not translate the variable name (the user of the website doesn't see the code). Just ensure that the code looks logical and clean.

Comment: You want to change variable name based on article?

Comment: Sorry it's not clear. The variable name is hard-coded into the page. So when hardcoding the view might write article = article.objects.get(slug="about-us") to pullup the right article, then the correct language and then pass it to the template using the same name: context = { ‘about-us’: query.first()}  The idea is to make everything as clear as possible. Ironically.